# Is there a way to get charcter one at a time in C?

Tags: c, string, char, character

I have a string of this type:
`%d.'\0'`
and I would like to parse it. For example if had this string
`12.'\0'`
I would like to read string character by character  (before the dot) and add number **12** in a integer variable.

Edit: So I have two processes that communicate by a message queue. Client send a message like: 12.5 and I have to separete 12 from 5. I don't want take an input. I have the string (12.5) inside a string variable and need to parse it beacuse I want 12 in a certain int variabile and 5 in another one.

Comment: Any decent text-book or tutorial should tell you how to read a single character. Either from standard input or from a specified file.

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are trying to do, please add more detail and the code you tried, and the exact input.

Comment: With that said, it's not really clear exactly what your problem is, or why reading single character would help you solve that problem. Please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Look into [atoi](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm). This allow to convert a string to an integer

Comment: @fuscati please never again propose to use the ugly *atoi*

Comment: @fuscati **NEVER** use `atoi()`.  It has no way to indicate any error of any type.

Comment: Sorry. I edited my question, hope this help you to understand my problem.

Comment: You can use function `strtol()` which will tell you where the first value ends. Or you could perhaps use `int result = sscanf(str, "%d.%d", &v1, &v2)` and check that `result == 2`.

Comment: Thanks: sscanf is perfect! Why check if result == 2?

Comment: You should always check the value returned by `scanfX` functions family. It is the number of successful conversions.

Answer (score 0):

i would use the function strtok
which is like function split in other languages
and function atoi for changing string to int

```
char e[] = "12.5";
char * num = strtok(e,".");
// x is the first number 
int x = atoi(num);
printf("%d\n",x);
// y is the number after the dot
num = strtok(NULL,".");
int y = atoi(num);
```

Comment: And what does `atoi()` return if you pass it the string "xyzzy"?

Comment: it will return 0